# Programmatically created instance does not execute any code

Tags: instancing, godot

I've created a new instance, positioned it, and added it to the scene like this:

```
const Player = preload("res://player.tscn")

func _physics_process(delta):
    if <outside display>:
        var newplayer = Player.instance()
        newplayer.position.x = 200
        get_tree().get_root().add_child(newplayer)
        queue_free()
```

This works to the extent that the player is created in the right position and starts falling down with gravity. But the new player does not respond to any input, nor does it do anything if I `print` things in the `_ready` function or the `_physics_process` function. It seems its script is just never executed at all.

I've tried not `queue_free()`'ing the old one, in case removing it is like removing its parent, but that doesn't help.

I've tried calling the `._ready()` function on it manually, but that doesn't work either.

I've tried calling `request_ready()` on the new player, but that doesn't run the `_ready()` function either.

In tutorials, this is usually all they do to get a new instance into the world, so I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Is that code part of your player's script or of another node's script? Please post all relevant code and the node structure. The code you've posted should actually work, so something important seems to be missing.

Comment: @skrx That's the player's script. The only other bit of relevant code would be the `set_physics_process(true)` in the `_ready` function. It's the only script I have at the moment. My root node is `world` (just a node) with `player` (RigidBody2D) as only relevant child (and some unused, static object called `target` as other child). The `player` has a Sprite and CollisionShape2D as children. Any idea what could be missing?

Comment: You wrote, "the new player does not respond to any input", but there's no input handling in your code. What do you expect to happen? Also, what's the actual code for `<outside display>`? -- I've created a simple example similar to yours in which I just move the player object to the right and spawn new players by pressing a key and it works correctly. BTW, the `preload` causes an error `possible cyclic resource inclusion`, but the program still works so I'm not sure if it has to do with the problem (I replaced it with `load`).

Comment: @skrx Oh right, I forgot that that's not in the code I posted. This is the full code for the player (the only script in the game so far): https://hastebin.com/oxomiwofux.vbs There's probably a lot to be improved but I'm having trouble finding documentation (e.g. I feel like the manual sin and cos calculation is probably unnecessary). Anyway, input handling is done there, and the whole thing is not executed for newly created instances if I don't call `newplayer.set_script(...)`.

Comment: Something is missing again in your new example: The `state` variable and the `STATE` enum. I've commented out the lines `if state != STATE.DEAD:` and `newplayer.set_script(get_script())` and it works correctly for me, so I guess the problem could have to do with the `state` variable. Where do you set or reset it?

Comment: I think I've found the reason for the error. If you've defined the `state` as a constant and later change it to `state = STATE.DEAD`, it will still be in this state when the next player is instantiated. If you make `state` a variable `var state`, it should work correctly. It seems constants are shared between instances. -- If you can confirm that this change fixes the problem, I'll post this as an answer.

Comment: @skrx Oh, I didn't think to look in that direction. Sorry, it seems I really shouldn't remove code for simplicity even if it seems 100% irrelevant. Anyway, if I remove the entire `state` thing, so it recreates player as soon as it's outside the map, `_ready` (and the other code) is never run, even if I try to call `request_ready()` on the new player (before or after adding it as child). I'm really wondering what obscure thing I'm running into now... Maybe I should start over, but I could just run into it again... would you mind comparing our files? I've uploaded mine to lgms.nl/tmp/proj2.zip

Comment: My script is almost identical to your previous script, I've only added `enum STATE {ALIVE, DEAD}` and `var state = STATE.ALIVE`. I've tested it without the state stuff and with a `var` and `const` `state`, and the `const state` caused the problem. I think it would be a good idea to create a new, clean test project and implement one feature of your original project after the other until it fails. Also, did you change any properties of your nodes or do they have the default values?

Comment: BTW, please don't post links to your files. Just add the relevant information (.gd and .tscn files) to your post.

Answer (score 1):

After browsing the autocomplete options some more, I found `set_script()`. It is apparently to be used like this:

```
newplayer.set_script(script_object)
```

I'm not sure how to find an arbitrary script object, but in case you want to attach the same script as is currently running, you can do this:

```
newplayer.set_script(get_script())
```

This needs to be done *before* adding it to the scene.

The full code is:

```
const Player = preload("res://player.tscn")

func _physics_process(delta):
    if <outside display>:
        var newplayer = Player.instance()
        newplayer.position.x = 200
        newplayer.set_script(get_script())
        get_tree().get_root().add_child(newplayer)
        queue_free()
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, if this suffices.

Comment: I don't think this is a good example for others to follow. There's some missing code here that's causing the problem. (You shouldn't have to re-assign scripts.)